# Inline-block div not taking width of percentaged width content

Tags: html, css, block

What I am trying to achieve is that `<div class="second">` takes the width of its content, but as you can see that the width of its children is percentage - that's why its not working. When I assign the children a fixed width like 200px, then its working as it should. Let me paste the code here:

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.third {
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRmpYY

Try changing 20% to 200px in this pen and you will understand what am I trying to do.

Comment: What is the desired outcome ? Why do you want their parent to have the width of its content ? Is it just for centering purpose ?

Comment: Set third class min-width:200px;

Comment: Yes, its for centering purpose.@Jake

Comment: @Rafv I want to make it responsive. So i can't assign min-width.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below CSS to achieve the desired result.

```
    .first { width: 100%; text-align: center; }
    .second {display: inline-block; width: auto; vertical-align: middle; }
    .third { width: 30%; display: inline-block; }
    img {width: 100%; display: block; }
```

The changes I have made in ".third" class are:

```
1. Removed the "float: left" 
2. Changed "display: block" to "display: inline-block"
```

Comment: "What I am trying to achieve is that <div class="second"> takes the width of its content"

Comment: Its important for designing purpose. I want to assign background-color to <div class="second">

Comment: Yes, I commented here after checking. sir.

Comment: Ok, can you please explain in steps, what exactly you are looking for. So that I can understand your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to centre your content, why don't you try `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` on your `.second` div.

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.third {
  width: 20%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you are open to changing your html, you could actually strip out the `.second` and just have 1 parent container.

You can also strip out a lot of your CSS too, and achieve the same result - like this:

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.third {
  width: 20%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="third">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

Updated with new understanding of the question:
Added `max-width` to the image, rather than have the width on `.third` div.

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second {
  background: purple;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The other guy was also able to produce the same result, in fact, I was able to do as well. My purpose is that the second div takes the width of its children, its important because of designing. I will assign background-color to the second div.

Comment: @UmerJaved I've amended my answer above and added some backgrounds so you can see how it's working - you just need to add a `max-width` to the image so that it's not stretching the parent div

Answer (score 0):

Your `inline-block` container (`second`) has `width: auto` set - so that means its value is determined by its contents. Same argument goes for the *floating* elements you have placed inside them (`third`):

> [**`10.3.9 'Inline-block', non-replaced elements in normal flow`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inlineblock-width)
>
> If 'width' is 'auto', the used value is the *shrink-to-fit* width as for *floating elements*.

---

#### When you specify the width

When you specify `width: 200px` for the `third`, the `second` container shrinks to this value.

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.third {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### When you don't have an intrinsic width specified

Now remove the *percentage width* for the `third` container - the width of `second` now is 1280px (if your viewport is smaller than this, it shrinks to the available width) - expand the below snippet fullscreen and inspect `second`:

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.third {
  /*width: 20%;*/
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now switch back `width: 20%` for the `third` element and see that it has *exactly* 20% of this value. This is in contrast to the fact that *percentages are resolved against the parent element*:

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.third {
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### What now?

It doesn't make much sense to me to set `width: 20%` when the parent container has no set width. So what I'd propose is that you can get about the same effect if you can use this percentage on the `second` container:

- add `width: 40%` to the `second` container
- use `inline-flex` display so that both `third` containers are placed next to each other

See demo below:

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: aliceblue;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}

.second {
  display: inline-flex; /* inline container */
  width: 40%; /* <-- 20% for each image section */
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.third {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No sir, because I want second to take the width of its content. Its important.